# Not able to change text of textview while sending intent from another Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I tried a lot before giving trouble to You all.
I am working on Chat Application in witch there is sever connection to every single Activity..

Toast works very fine on Messege Activity so there is No problem in sending Intent.
But when I try to update UI it gives me error.

I am sending intent like this

```
intentt.putExtra("name", values[arg2]);
```

and getting intent like below

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String id = extras.getString("name");
```

Code where I have set id in `TextView`

```
else if (id != null) {

            // tx.setText(id);

            Thread thread = new Thread() {

                public void run() {

                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,
                                    "Something happened.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                            tx.setText(id);
                        }
                    });

                };
            };
            thread.start();

        }
```

I got below mention error..

```
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at at.vcity.androidim.Messaging$2$1.run(Messaging.java:122)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-14 12:17:00.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: probably `tx` is null make sure you are initializing

Comment: TextView tx;    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmessege); is have used like this

Comment: post some more code and initializing `tx` before starting Thread

Comment: add one check if(tx!=null){tx.setText(id);}. See error still persist or not.

Comment: I initialize before thread creation...

Comment: @Vivek error is not showing but value also not get display..

Comment: did you debug your code ? and where you are getting id from ? and how please post some more code..

Comment: I updated my code please check..

Comment: Rituraj suman i have updated my code please refer it. it will tell your exact problem.

Comment: what is the data type of your values[] array is it string or int...

Comment: @Riturajsuman: i have used your code and its working fine for me.. Toast is there and value setting in textview. Passing values[arg] from one activity to another.

Comment: why its not working for me..? i posted my error as well....its really very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to this if you are in activity. It will tell you what your problem exactly.

```
else if (id != null) {
                    // tx.setText(id);

                    Thread thread = new Thread() {

                        public void run() {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,
                                            "Something happened.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();


                             if(tx!=null)
                             {
                                if(id!=null && id.length()>0)
                                {
                                   tx.setText(id);
                                  }
                                else
                                 {
                                Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,"id is null or is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
                             else
                             {
                              Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,"Tx is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              }

                                }
                }); 

                        };
                    };
                    thread.start();

                }
```

Comment: Now it it doesnt show error but text value also not get updated

Comment: @Riturajsuman Use the debugger or Log.e() methods to see if `tv` is `null`

Comment: Ok. you got the problem what actually is. Replace this line intentt.putExtra("name", values[arg2]);  with this two lines. Log.e("",""+values[arg2]); intentt.putExtra("name", values[arg2]); and see what log is printing.